# What is the building photographed in this stock wallpaper?

Tags: 10.10, desktop-background, design

I'm sure I've seen a picture of the full building somewhere. The image is a blue-tinted display of the building's facade - facing into a blue sky. It's a part of the stock wallpapers in Ubuntu 10.10 (Maverick).

Can someone help me identify this building? I can't be the first - or the only - person to be interested in knowing.

[image: Architecture Wallpaper]

Comment: No idea, but [the original is on flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/elslunko/4897785821/in/pool-1468716@N24) if it helps.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is the Walt Disney Concert hall in Los Angeles, designed by [Frank Gehry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFWQd.jpg).

From the photographer's site: http://edltphoto.com/2010/09/ubuntu-blue/

> My photo of a portion of the Walt
>   Disney Concert hall in Downtown Los
>   Angeles.

A full sized picture of the concert hall is included below, a [description is found here](http://www.laphil.com/philpedia/wdch-overview.cfm)

[image: Concert Hall]

Comment: Anyone see irony in the dichotomy between freedom of ubuntu and the restricted free culture promoted by Disney?

Comment: @Jay Not necessarily. It's like [The Cathedral and the Bazaar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cathedral_and_the_Bazaar) - the centrally planned cathedral vs. the more or less free-for-all bazaar. Two different cultures, but I believe the world is big enough for both of them ;)

Comment: Irony? I see a pretty building that someone took a picture of.

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! The Concert Hall was designed by [Frank Gehry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frank_Gehry) - a name every architecture geek knows :) There is a good description of the design from LAPhil [here](http://www.laphil.com/philpedia/wdch-overview.cfm).

Comment: @David: links here work like this: [Descriptive text](URL)

Comment: @oKtosiTe: Thanks... Got it already - finally!  Editediteditedit :)

Comment: @David: MediaWiki? ;-)

Comment: Indeed it is the Concert Hall. Shot on a beautiful Los Angeles day, and processed within Ubuntu no less!

Comment: In response to @Jay: architecture is almost universally copyright-free. How about that?